# Como enviar e-mail em C#

Tags: c#, envio-de-email

De tanto que pesquisei, vi a grande dificuldade que as pessoas tem para o envio de e-mail, utilizando a plataforma C#, por isso estou aqui disponibilizando a forma que encontrei para a realização deste feito.